# Logout with Facebook SDK in Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hello I have a problem with the logout method of Facebook SDK API. I doesnt close the session. I want to close it in the onload of my index theres my method

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function cerrarSesion() {
    FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
          alert(response.status);
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                document.location.reload();
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I call the method in the onload of my index but doesnt works

```
<body onload="cerrarSesion();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of on onload, perform the logout event after the SDK has initialized if FB.getLoginStatus shows the user is indeed logged in:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{your-app-id}',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                          // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.logout();
      }
    });
}
```